# Do the set of functions mapping real numbers to real numbers form a group under composition?

Tags: group-theory

Consider the set of functions $\left\lbrace f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R\right\rbrace$.

Define $f_1 \star f_2$ to be the composition $f_1 \circ f_2$.
With the operation $\star$ is this set of functions a group? - If so, then justify.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: What should be the identity of this group?  Are there always inverses?

Comment: If $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$, what would $f^{-1} $ be?

Comment: @Nate: Is the identity of the group just f itself?

Comment: @copper.hat, I'm not sure. Does this mean there is no inverse?

Comment: @flamingohats: Correct, because there can be no function $g$ such that $g * f$ is the identity.

Answer (score 2):

No they do not because the inverse does not belong there.

However, the bijections $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ (i.e., one-to-one and onto) form a group (non-abelian).